# Where to put copyright notices in a minimal Mac app's UI?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

I am doing a minimal port of a simple iPhone/iPad app (think 2D casual game with a single view) to the Mac (almost nothing has changed in the UI, except swapping touchable Cocoa Touch UI elements for mouse-clickable Cocoa UI elements).  In the iPhone app, a little "i" button brings up a text view containing basic instructions, followed by all the required (possibly lengthy) BSD/MIT/Apache/Artistic/et.al. copyright notices **and their associated disclaimers** for any random borrowed code.

The ported Mac app is intended to be distributed from the Mac App store, so additional README files outside the app bundle/sandbox can't be used.  I note that many Mac App store apps do not put this text in the About... box, or use a little "i" button like iPhone apps.

So where do I put the equivalent README text in a Mac App Store app?

I would like this text to be included with the Mac app so that it's viewable from within the app even when the Mac is completely off-line.

ADDED:
I see recommendations for putting all this text in the About... dialog, but, if so, my guess is that many apps are skimping on all the required text that seems to go with many of these licenses (I've seen a few with a page or two of required disclaimers. Which Mac app has all that in the About... dialog?)

Comment: Normally this would go in the "About MyApp" dialog which the user accesses via the menu item `MyApp` => `About MyApp`.

Comment: Typical About... dialog boxes are much smaller than many of these licenses required text.  If you have several licenses...

Comment: for cases where you have too much information to display in the main "About..." dialog you would typically have buttons in the dialog, e.g. "Credits", which take you to additional dialogs, or you might just make the About... dialog scrollable (e.g. BBEdit does this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put a Credits.html or Credits.rtf file in your bundle, it'll automatically be displayed in the dialog that's shown after clicking the "About MyApp" item in the main menu.

Comment: A pile of BSD/MIT/Apache/etc. licenses is a little bit too long for an About... dialog.

Comment: The About dialog does scroll, but you could also link to another HTML or PDF file (either in your bundle or online) from there.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a Mac app includes an «About» window, with the application's icon, name, version number and author.

If you have credits to display, you may display them on that window, if it's only a few lines.
If you have a long text, you should add a «credits» button on the «About» window, that eventually opens a specific credits window, with the text you want.

Comment: So are you recommending custom About... and Credits windows (with associated xibs, controllers, views, etc.) for this, instead of using Credits.html?

Comment: Why do you want to load a specific HTML file? Simply design an XIB file with your credits, and loads it when the credits button is pressed (with a controller, right).

Comment: You'll also have to do this with an HTML file. But designing with InterfaceBuilder may be simpler than loading a web view with a local file.